# Parameters in abstract method (Java 7)

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, abstract-class, java-7

I have some test JavaFX app and the code has a lot of similar parts regard of database.
Just for example:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Person.getURL(), Person.getDBUSERNAME(), Person.getDBPASSWORD())) {
                String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users (users.user_name," +
                        "users.current_balance) VALUES (?, ?)";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, newUserName);
                preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(newBalance));

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So I want to make an abstract class SqlWorkClass with an abstract method updateDatabaseInfo.

```
public abstract class SqlWorkClass {
    public abstract void updateDatabaseInfo() throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

And 3 classes inherited of SqlWorkClass – DatabaseInsertClass, DatabaseUpdateClass and DatabaseSelectClass. 
But the problem is I have to use different parameters for method updateDatabaseInfo for each class.

```
public class DatabaseInsertClass extends SqlWorkClass {

    @Override
    public void updateDatabaseInfo(String newUserName, String newBalance) throws ClassNotFoundException{
            //some actions with code above
}

public class DatabaseUpdateClass extends SqlWorkClass {

    @Override
    public void updateDatabaseInfo(String param1, String param2, String param3) throws ClassNotFoundException{
            //some actions with code above
}

public class DatabaseSelectClass extends SqlWorkClass {

        @Override
        public void updateDatabaseInfo(String param1) throws ClassNotFoundException{
                //some actions with code above
    }
```

Obviously I can't do this. So how can I solve this problem? Maybe I should use interface or something else instead of abstract class? Hope for your advice guys! 
p.s. I use Java 7.

Comment: you can use an `Object []` array as super typer parameter and then you can call the supermethod in your sub classes like this: `super.updateDatabaseInfo(new Object[]{param1,param2,...})`. if the method should do the same for all 3 subclasses, why does it need different parameter then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parameter object instead of a list of parameters. Your super class defines the parameter object class and uses it as parameter for the method. The sub classes then implement specific classes:

```
public abstract class SqlWorkClass<I extends Input>
{
    public abstract void updateDatabaseInfo(I input)
        throws ClassNotFoundException;
}
public abstract class Input {}

public class DatabaseInsertClass
    extends SqlWorkClass<InsertInput>
{
    @Override
    public void updateDatabaseInfo(InsertInput input)
        throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String param1 = input.newUserName;
        String param2 = input.newBalance;
    }
}
public abstract class InsertInput
    extends Input
{
    public final String newUserName, newBalance;

    public InsertInput(String newUserName, String newBalance)
    {
        this.newUserName = newUserName;
        this.newBalance = newBalance;
    }
}
```

The advantage here that you do not have to rely on convention to get the parameter types and names right. You have nicely defined inputs of specific types.

---

You would then use your classes like this:

```
new DatabaseInsertClass().updateDatabaseInfo(new InsertInput(param1, param2));
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain a bit more, please?
I use the example you give me, but what kind of parameters should i use, when I call the method `updateDatabaseInfo` ? 
I mean Im trying to call the method from the other class -`new DatabaseInsertClass().updateDatabaseInfo(param1, param2);` . What type of `param1` and `param2` should I use now? Looks like i can't use `String`, but have to use `InsertInput` type. How can I make `String` to `InsertInput`.

Comment: @oiDistortion I have added a small example of how to use it. As I said, using those parameter object types tells you exactly what you have to pass: a database insert needs insert input. You create insert input by calling the constructor with 2 string parameters. Using good names for your parameters and/or documenting them in JavaDoc will help you understand the code if you come back to it in a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass those parameters in constructors of `DatabaseInsertClass`, `DatabaseUpdateClass` and `DatabaseSelectClass`. This way you can use `updateDatabaseInfo()` with no parameters.
For every operation you will have to create a new instance of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to update one record at a time, you could use a `HashMap` to store your updated values like so:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put('id', '112342');
data.put('name', 'CaveJohnson');
data.put('address', 'ApertureSciencesRoad');
```

And then your abstract classes method would be:

```
public void updateDatabaseInfo(Map<String, String> updateData) throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

Implementing classes would not even need to know the name of the data headers:

```
public void updateDatabaseInfo(Map<String, String> updateData) throws ClassNotFoundException{
     for(String key:updateData.keys()){
         //Use Prepared Statements to generate a query with `key` being your field 
         //name and `updateData.get(key)` being the value to place in that field
     }

}
```